# waiting for a page to load using selenium explicit wait python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I am a beginner using python3 for windows.
My problem is I am trying to scrape the title and votes (likes/dislikes) from a youtube playlist and can't seem to get my script to wait for the next page to load before taking the votes on the next page, and again until the playlist is over.

Instead it merely takes the title, and votes from first page repeats this and clicks on the next page only once, after everything is copied.

I googled and looked at other posts, figuring an explicit wait may need to be invoked, yet it still doesn't appear to work.

Current script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2bnMiScBRfQ&list=PLx1Dr6w7DLoLfPixTug9c8xrTkGUsyhkQ&index=')

videosInPlaylist = []

for x in range(1, 4):
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1.title'))).text

    positiveVotes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-text:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)'))).text

    negativeVotes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-text:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)'))).text

    currentVideo = [title, positiveVotes, negativeVotes]

    nextVideo = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-playlist-panel-video-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3)')))

    videosInPlaylist.append(currentVideo)
    nextVideo.click()
print(videosInPlaylist)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the video title has been changed. See my code below. I created a custom wait class to compare new title and old title. 
However, you might face an ads video which will block `nextVideo.click()`, you need to handle that to make this code works completely.

```
class element_text_changed(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, oldTitle):
        self.locator = locator
        self.oldTitle = oldTitle

    def __call__(self, browser):
        wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
        titleElement = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(self.locator))
        newTitle = titleElement.text.strip()
        print("OLD: " + self.oldTitle + ", NEW: " + newTitle)
        if len(self.oldTitle)==0 or (self.oldTitle!=newTitle):
            return titleElement
        else:
            return False

oldTitle = ''
for x in range(1, 7):
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    title = wait.until(element_text_changed((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1.title'), oldTitle)).text
    print(title)
    oldTitle = title

    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    positiveVotes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-toggle-button-renderer.style-text:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1) > yt-formatted-string:nth-child(2)'))).text
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  :)  I did some digging and found the url_changes method which is really helpful.  Selenium is awesome again!!  And yeah the ads are a bit pesky...I have to find something to do with them...